Canvas with webgl becomes broken after some time
I have a page where I use multiple canvases with webgl2 context. When I load or refresh page everything works good (rendering in canvases). But if I go to other tab in browser or switch focus to other app, and then return back to my page some canvases may become broken.
In my case "broken" means following:
Double buffering seems not to work correctly. In one buffer drawing seems to be working, in other buffer not. Broken buffer just displays the same frame each time. So I see blinking in canvas.
I want to know if I can fix such behavior or somehow trigger if canvas is broken.

Does this happen regardless of browser? It may be a browser bug.

Please, try editing the question and put a minimal code example to reproduce the problem you're having. Maybe then we can detect something that would be clogging your threads or corrupting the data.

This could use a [mcve]. A browser bug is far less likely than a standard code bug in your specific implementation, and even if it was a browser bug (or unusual behavior), a runnable example is still necessary to make that determination and eliminate any programming errors.

Seems that happens only in desktop Firefox browser, but not sure. There is nothing special about rendering code. To reproduce one can use list of canvases (10 for example) with any webgl rendering. Then one should leave the page and do some other stuff for unknown time. After returning to page this issue can be found.
